# Adding blank line to beginning of formatted CSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm trying to remove quote marks from a csv before bulk inserting using an SP (and a FMT file). The problem is our FMT file is counting on a blank line before the headers to process it, so the SP fails if there is no starting blank line. I would like to add a blank line before the headers somehow.

This is my code

```
public Path truncateQuoteMarks(Path path) throws Exception {

        String pipeDelimitedFilename = path.toAbsolutePath().toString();

        Path convertedFilename = Paths.get(pipeDelimitedFilename.substring(0, pipeDelimitedFilename.lastIndexOf(".csv")) + "_no_quotes.csv");

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toAbsolutePath().toString()))), '|', CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

        //skips headers
        reader.skip(1);

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(convertedFilename.toAbsolutePath().toString()), '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

        String[] currentLine;
        while((currentLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            writer.writeNext(currentLine);
        }

        writer.close();

        return convertedFilename;
}
```

I tried using `writer.writeNext(new String[]{});` but it still fails. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try to put an empty string in the `writer.writeNext(new String[]{""})`? Since the array of Strings is empty, it's possible no value at all is written on the file when the call is made

Comment: You could use a filewriter then just use the newline character `\n`

Comment: @Sirmyself yup, so when using `writer.writeNext(new String[]{});` or `writer.writeNext(new String[]{""});` the result only has headers. I also tried removing the `reader.skip(1);` and I got the same result. The code works as is, but it's missing that first blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write to the FileWriter directly:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(convertedFilename.toAbsolutePath().toString());
fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw, '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

Then continue as before.